# Move the right view over the centre view in DeckView Example

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to move the right view controller over the centre controller in ViewDeck example.Now the centre controller is moved along with the right view this must not happen.Can anyone please help me to solve this.

leftMenuView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftMenu"];

```
rightMenuView = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuView"];
centerController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainPage"];
navCtr = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];

mainController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainView"];

navCtr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainController];
```

[centerController.view addSubview:navCtr.view];

self.deckController =  [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerController
                                                                 leftViewController:leftMenuView
                                                                  rightViewController:rightMenuView];

self.deckController.rightSize = 50;
 self.deckController.leftSize = 50;

Comment: can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Currently moving a side view controller over the center view controller is not possible in ViewDeck. If this is a feature you want to have, I would encourage you to add a +1 to this feature request: https://github.com/ViewDeck/ViewDeck/issues/471

Comment: I didn't get you. Did you meant that there exists no possible solution?

Comment: I mean that there exists no solution that you can simply turn on in ViewDeck. You can of course integrate this yourself as ViewDeck is open source, but you might have to change a lot as the animation code of ViewDeck currently is very static. This is one of the things I am planning to clean up a lot in the future, to make such things easier.